# Initializing a 2D array with only the number of rows

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

So I'm a bit confused about how to use a 2D Array in Java if you only declare the number of rows at first.
For example:

```java
int[][] x = new int[5][];
```

But how would you go on about filling those 5 rows? I'm thinking you need to declare the size of each one of the rows first, but I can't figure out a way to do so. If I try to do something like:

```java
x[0][0] = 5;
```

The compiler tells me that `x[0]` is null.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you tried to define a 2d array: firstly you specified the numbers of row, but you didn't specified the number of columns and its necessary.

for example I defined the 2 columns for the first row and assigned the value:

```
int[][] x = new int[5][];
x[0] = new int[2];
x[0][0] = 5;
System.out.println(x[0][0]);
```

for better undestanding of 2d-arrays you need to read more:

> https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1):

Simply do it:

```java
public class ClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Assignment of multi-dimensional array
        int[][] multiarray = new int[2][3];
        // assign value to row "0" and col "0" index
        multiarray[0][0] = 23;
        System.out.println("My Age is:" + multiarray[0][0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An element of a 2d array is a 1d array. If you define an array directly `new int[5][4]` then length of each row is `4`, otherwise it may vary. When you create a 2d array with undefined row length, each element of it, actually 1d array, is not initialized yet and is `null`. When you create 1d array of `int[]` it is initialized with zeros by default. If you define 2d array directly the elements of its rows are initialized with zeros.

#### Initialization of 2d array

You can define column length without row length:

```java
int[][] arr = new int[5][];

arr[0] = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
arr[3] = new int[2];
arr[3][1] = 9;
arr[4] = new int[]{3, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7};
```

```
// output:
[1, 2, 3]
null
null
[0, 9]
[3, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7]
```

You can define column and row length:

```java
int[][] arr2 = new int[3][3];
arr2[0][0] = 1;
```

```
// output:
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

You can define each element of the 2d array at creation time, optionally with reserved rows for further operations:

```java
int[][] arr3 = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}, null};
```

```
// output:
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6]
null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `x[0][0]` because no columns exists at row `x[0]`.
You will need to initialize every column in a row before using it:

```java
x[0] = new int[5];
x[1] = new int[5];
```

or use a loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x[i] = new int[5];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int ROWS = 5;
int COLUMNS = 12;
int[][] x = new int[ROWS][];
```

Initialize the values of all `ROWS` to zero:

```java
IntStream.range(0, ROWS).forEach(i -> {
    x[i] = new int[COLUMNS];
});
```

If You want to initialize to a different value eg. `-1`:

```java
IntStream.range(0, ROWS).forEach(i -> {
    x[i] = new int[COLUMNS];
    Arrays.fill(x[i], -1);
});
```