# Why is row size required and column size optional in 2D / 3D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I always get confused why does the 2D array in Java has a strict requirement for declaring the size of the row but not the column, this confuses further with 3D and 4D arrays.

```java
// Invalid, 2D array with no row and no column?
int[][] arr = new int[][];
// Valid, 2D array of size 2X3
int[][] arr = new int[2][3];
// Valid, column size is not specified, size of 2D array?
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
// Valid, column size is not specified, size of 3D array?
int[][][] arr = new int[2][][];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It allows you to delay decision regarding the number of columns, as well as define a different number of columns for different rows.

For example:

```
int [][] arr = new int[2][];

arr[0] = new int[5];
arr[1] = new int[3];
```

The first row of the array has 5 columns, but the second row has only 3 columns.
This is not possible if you specify the number of columns when you declare the 2D array.

It may become less confusing is you think of a multi-dimensional array as a 1 dimensional array whose elements are themselves arrays of a lower dimension.

So a 2 dimensional int array (`int[][]`) is a 1 dimensional array whose elements are `int` arrays (`int[]`).

You can instantiate this array by specifying the number of elements:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
```

which gives you an array of two `int[]` elements, where the `2` elements are initialized to `null`.

This is similar to initializing an array of some reference type:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[2];
```

which gives you an array of two `Object` elements, where the `2` elements are initialized to `null`.

The `new int[2][3]` instantiation is actually the special case - since it instantiates both the outer array (the one having 2 elements) and the inner arrays (each having 3 elements), which are the elements of the outer array.

Answer (score 0):

You can add curly brackets `{}` to the end. This is valid, an empty 2D array with no rows and no columns:

```java
int[][] arr = new int[][]{};
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Initializing a 2D array with only the number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65593464/16119950)

• [Array declaration and initialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67793106/16119950)</sup>